# How to join a very large lucene resultset to a real large sql table [10's of million rows]

Tags: c#, sql-server, architecture, lucene.net, large-data

Here is the problem,

I have a SQL DB with your regular customer, product, order schema but HUGE. [Each table has 10s of million rows]. there is also a large table with order_email [apprx 100 million rows]. This table holds all email communication associated with an order. I have implemented a full text search using on top of the order_email which works fine.

Now I want to extend the email search functionality to filter this based on other domain objects. i.e to answer queries like

- show customers who sent an email with the phrase 'never gonna give you up'
- show orders which has an associated email with the phrase 'more ponies'.

The implementation is to do an intersection/join of the lucene result and a sql result but I can't think of a way to do this without running into issues due to the SIZE of the tables and index involved

### My failing approaches

- Brute force. Adding most of my DB columns as lucene fields. This is equivalent of denormalizing my entire DB  and creating a Lucene Index (size in Terrabytes) with all columns as fields. performance sucks and cost prohibitive.
- Getting the Lucene result set, getting the OrderID from it and querying the DB like  SELECT * from Order where OrderID IN(*ORDERIDs from Lucene*). This doesn't work because the email search could yield a million orderIDs, which makes the SQL query to perform poorly if at all.
- Doing the join in application code, but iterating over the sql result and the lucene result. This  means based on the size of the results, a single query could load 2 multi million row datasets and iterate over them, trashing CPU and memory.

**Thoughts on how I can structure this join/intersection of 2 large datasets?**

p.s: first one to suggest hadoop is a rotten egg. Wish I could, but we don't have the budget for more hardware.

Comment: Ok, never mind last comment. Look, if you want to show a resultset based on customers table, filtered by lucene, you can do it in two steps like your point#2. However, don't show a million orderIDs to your app user - page them. And then SELECT * from Order where OrderID IN *(ORDERIDs from Lucene, count is constrained by your page size)*

Comment: Is it imperative that your results always include the fields that match? For example when searching customers who sent an email with phrase X, must you show that email in the results or is it sufficient to show just the customer?

Comment: Our index covers a table with 300Million rows, and a couple with 10+ million rows, and we're only approaching 15GB or so. How do you know it will be on the order of Terabytes? Have you tried not storing the actual text in Lucene and just do a SQL look up to show the results?

Comment: I meant to say if I denormalized the entire DB and indexed it, *then* the index would be in TBs. How do you match the results from your index to SQL? do you do a "select from tbl where id in (ids from index)?"

Comment: Yeah something like that. Of course that assumes you are paging your results, because you could have lots of search results.

Comment: That makes sense, but in my case I want to run some aggregates on the sql side, so paging is not an option. Maybe the lack of a good answer for this question is an indicator I shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: I think you should give putting all your data in Lucene a shot. It's possible it won't use as much storage as you think. Probably worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

Like OzrenTkalcecKrznaric said in the comments to the question, paging is your friend. (Remember that the single most power algorithm ever developed is "divide and conquer".)